# Initializing a symmetric Theano dmatrix from its upper triangle

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, theano

I'm trying to fit a Theano model that is parametrized in part by a symmetric matrix `A`. In order to enforce the symmetry of `A`, I want to be able to construct `A` by passing in just the values in the upper triangle.

The equivalent numpy code might look something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def make_symmetric(p, n):
    A = np.empty((n, n), P.dtype)
    A[np.triu_indices(n)] = p
    A.T[np.triu_indices(n)] = p

# output matrix will be (n, n)
n = 4

# parameter vector
P = np.arange(n * (n + 1) / 2)

print make_symmetric(P, n)
# [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
#  [ 1.  4.  5.  6.]
#  [ 2.  5.  7.  8.]
#  [ 3.  6.  8.  9.]]
```

However, since symbolic tensor variables don't support item assignment, I'm struggling to find a way to do this in Theano.

The closest thing I could find is `theano.tensor.diag`, which allows me to construct a symbolic matrix from its diagonal:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as te

P = te.dvector('P')
D = te.diag(P)
get_D = theano.function([P], D)

print get_D(np.arange(1, 5))
# [[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  3.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  4.]]
```

Whilst there is also a `theano.tensor.triu` function, this cannot be used to construct a matrix from the upper triangle, but rather returns a copy of an array with the lower triangular elements zeroed.

Is there any way to construct a Theano symbolic matrix from its upper triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `theano.tensor.triu` and add the result to its transpose, then subtract the diagonal.

Copy+Pasteable code:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
theano.config.floatX = 'float32'

mat = T.fmatrix()
sym1 = T.triu(mat) + T.triu(mat).T
diag = T.diag(T.diagonal(mat))
sym2 = sym1 - diag

f_sym1 = theano.function([mat], sym1)
f_sym2 = theano.function([mat], sym2)

m = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3).astype(np.float32)

print m
# [[ 0.  1.  2.]
#  [ 3.  4.  5.]
#  [ 6.  7.  8.]]
print f_sym1(m)
# [[  0.   1.   2.]
#  [  1.   8.   5.]
#  [  2.   5.  16.]]
print f_sym2(m)
# [[ 0.  1.  2.]
#  [ 1.  4.  5.]
#  [ 2.  5.  8.]]
```

Does this help? This approach would require a full matrix to be passed, but would ignore everything below the diagonal and symmetrize using the upper triangle.

We can also take a look at the derivative of this function. In order not to deal with a multidimensional output, we can e.g. look at the gradient of the sum of the matrix entries

```
sum_grad = T.grad(cost=sym2.sum(), wrt=mat)
f_sum_grad = theano.function([mat], sum_grad)

print f_sum_grad(m)
# [[ 1.  2.  2.]
#  [ 0.  1.  2.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

This reflects the fact that the upper triangular entries figure doubly in the sum.

---

Update: You can do normal indexing:

```
n = 4
num_triu_entries = n * (n + 1) / 2

triu_index_matrix = np.zeros([n, n], dtype=int)
triu_index_matrix[np.triu_indices(n)] = np.arange(num_triu_entries)
triu_index_matrix[np.triu_indices(n)[::-1]] = np.arange(num_triu_entries)

triu_vec = T.fvector()
triu_mat = triu_vec[triu_index_matrix]

f_triu_mat = theano.function([triu_vec], triu_mat)

print f_triu_mat(np.arange(1, num_triu_entries + 1).astype(np.float32))

# [[  1.   2.   3.   4.]
#  [  2.   5.   6.   7.]
#  [  3.   6.   8.   9.]
#  [  4.   7.   9.  10.]]
```

---

Update: To do all of this dynamically, one way is to write a symbolic version of `triu_index_matrix`. This can be done with some shuffling of `arange`s. But probably I am overcomplicating.

```
n = T.iscalar()
n_triu_entries = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
r = T.arange(n)

tmp_mat = r[np.newaxis, :] + (n_triu_entries - n - (r * (r + 1)) / 2)[::-1, np.newaxis]
triu_index_matrix = T.triu(tmp_mat) + T.triu(tmp_mat).T - T.diag(T.diagonal(tmp_mat))

triu_vec = T.fvector()
sym_matrix = triu_vec[triu_index_matrix]

f_triu_index_matrix = theano.function([n], triu_index_matrix)
f_dynamic_sym_matrix = theano.function([triu_vec, n], sym_matrix)

print f_triu_index_matrix(5)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
#  [ 1  5  6  7  8]
#  [ 2  6  9 10 11]
#  [ 3  7 10 12 13]
# [ 4  8 11 13 14]]
print f_dynamic_sym_matrix(np.arange(1., 16.).astype(np.float32), 5)
# [[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.]
#  [  2.   6.   7.   8.   9.]
#  [  3.   7.  10.  11.  12.]
#  [  4.   8.  11.  13.  14.]
#  [  5.   9.  12.  14.  15.]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose might fall back on something like this, but I'm still hoping there's a solution that will allow me to only pass the upper triangle. I need to take partial derivatives of my loss function w.r.t. the model parameters in `p`, and I'm sure Theano won't be able to do this as efficiently if there are a bunch of spurious coefficients around due to me having to pass in a full matrix rather than just the upper triangle.

Comment: I see a slight chance it may optimize that away, but I don't know enough of the internals to be able to figure that out. It is setting the lower triangle to 0 hard. I don't see how that can go through a gradient. The gradient will probably be in matrix shape, but only have non-zero coefs on the upper part, so I don't think this will incur any extra instability.

Comment: I added a gradient calculation. No idea whether this scales, but in any case, giving the parameters as a 1D array won't save you more than half. Stability / spurious coefficients shouldn't really be an issue though. However, I would also be interested in the functionality you are requesting. It seems generally useful.

Comment: Just realized you can actually do normal indexing. I did it using a numpy index array, so it's static wrt to the matrix size, but I don't see why this shouldn't work dynamically with theano variables, too.

Comment: Awesome - that will work nicely for my case, since `n` is known at compile time. I don't see any way this could work if `n` is dynamic, though, since `triu_index_matrix` would then also need to be a symbolic matrix, which won't support item assignment.

Comment: In general you are probably right. In this specific case, I was able to generate the index matrix analytically from an `arange`. I added an update for completeness sake.

Comment: +99 for this!! I was trying to mess with scan but this saved my day! The normal indexing will be especially handy for more complicated indexing!!