# A Pure Pythonic Pairwise Euclidean distance of rows of a numpy ndarray

Tags: numpy, matrix, euclidean-distance, theano

I have a matrix of size (n_classes, n_features) and i want to compute the pairwise euclidean distance of each pair of classes so the output would be a (n_classes, n_classes) matrix where each cell has the value of euclidean_distance(class_i, class_j).

I know that there is this scipy spatial distances (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/spatial.distance.html)  and sklearn.metric.euclidean distances (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html) but i want to use this in Theano software so i need a pure mathematical formula rather than functions that compute the results.

for example i need a series of transformations like A = X * B, D = X.T-X, results = D.T something that contains just matrix mathematical operations not functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886374/pdist-for-theano-tensor/ ?

Comment: Yes thanks, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using numpy broadcasting as shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kastnerkyle/7a985f63c1ba92ac8bca). It should be straightforward to convert this to Theano code, or just reference @eickenberg's comment above, since he's the one who showed me how to do this!

Comment: I also found [this code](http://trunghuyduong.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/pair-wise-weighted-euclidean-distance.html) which is doing the same thing. Thanks Kyle.

Comment: +1 :) - if I read your gist correctly, in `np.exp(-(x1[np.newaxis, :, :] - x2[:, np.newaxis, :])[:, :, 0] ** 2).T` you seem to be collecting only the distance on the first coordinate. Wouldn't you want `np.exp(-((x1[np.newaxis, :, :] - x2[:, np.newaxis, :]) ** 2).sum(2)).T` ?

Comment: Yeah... that looks like a bug. All features should matter :)